# How to create a method that tests a current date in 3 different formats?

Tags: c#

```
    public void Date()
    {
        setMonth(3);
        setDay(26);
        setYear(1992);
    }


    //method getDate
    public void getDate(int m, int d, int y)
    {
        if ( == )

        else
            if ( == )

            else
                if ( == )

    }
```

Just can't seem to get the methods I have been using to work, and testing it and creating an object that would even start up the test.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What formats? What “testing”?

Comment: What is this method supposed to do?

Comment: Your previous question was closed because it showed little to no effort. This one will be closed on similar grounds.

Comment: the method is suppose to display the date i have there in 3 different formats like mm-dd-yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Check the ***DateTime.TryParseExact*** method, you could do something like:

```
string str = "2013-06-06";
string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact(str, formats, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

But keep in mind that testing this way is really brittle, so be sure that no ambiguity can exist.

Comment: My professor is picky so he wants me to stay in the parameters of what he teaches us.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getDate(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1 )
           //Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",yourdatetimeVariablehere);
        else
            if (i == 2)
                //Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",yourdatetimeVariablehere);
            else
                if (i == 3)
                   //you get the picture.................
    }
```

Comment: so when i call on the getDate method its gonna pull the date from my constructor and set it up in 3 different formats?

Comment: if you have datetime variable in your class,assign it in constructor then call this method

Comment: //3 attributes setters and getters each
    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;   
    }
    public void setMonth(int m)
    {
        month = m;
    }

    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(int d)
    {
        day = d;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int y)
    {
        year = y;
    }

Comment: Thats whats in my class, besides the set date and constructor, what would necessarily be the date time variable?

Comment: DateTime dt = new DateTime(yourintyearvariable, yourintmonthvariable, yourintdayvariable);    but your datetime dt would be declared outside

Comment: well mines public class Date, so how do I insert it to utilize all the setters and getters to put the date in that format?

Comment: Date format1 = new Date(03, 26, 1992); thats the object in the DateTest right?